# how can i allow requests to host from docker container

Tags: docker, bigbluebutton

Blocked host: xxxxxxx
To allow requests to xxxxxxxxxxx, add the following to your environment configuration:
config.hosts << "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: There are some possibilities: https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/24

Comment: Similar question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using http://host.docker.internal rather than http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost

This will work on your dev machine only when you are running docker for windows or docker for mac